# How do I program my progress bar in combination with asynchronous calls?

Tags: c#, xaml, asynchronous, windows-phone-8, progress-bar

**First of all, my experience with Windows Phone 8 developing is not very big but some things look like ASP.NET Framework with which I am more familiar with.**

I want a indeterminate progress bar that shows up when doing a web request in background and that hides when the request was handled.

My solution works but I am not happy with it 
(and the progressBar/Text were inside one pivot element to test the functionality) 
We have the following:

A XAML Page called "MainPage" with Pivot elements.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage>

...

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- HERE I want the progress bar and loading-text to show up if possible -->
            <TextBlock Name="ProgressText" Text="Loading..." Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            <ProgressBar Name="ProgressBar" Visibility="Collapsed" IsIndeterminate="True"/>
        <!-- HERE I want the progress bar and loading-text to show up if possible -->

        <phone:Pivot Title="MyTitle">
            <!-- Here are my PivotItems -->
        </phone:Pivot>

    </Grid>

<phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

My codebehind looks like this:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(
    App.ViewModel.LoadSomething();
}
```

The Function LoadSomething() shows/hides the progress bar and loading-text.
This is the part with which I am not happy with:

```
// Method of the ViewModel
public void LoadSomething()
{
    //Showing progress bar and loading-text
    var mainPage = (MainPage)App.RootFrame.Content;
    mainPage.ProgressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    mainPage.ProgressText.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

    // form the URI
    UriBuilder fullUri = new UriBuilder(string.Format("http://somepage..."));

    // initialize a new WebRequest
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(fullUri.Uri);

    // set up the state object for the async request
    UpdateState state = new UpdateState();
    state.AsyncRequest = request;

    // start the asynchronous request
    request.BeginGetResponse(
        new AsyncCallback(HandleResponse),
        state);
}

private void HandleResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    // Here happens logic and stuff


    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            // Here happens logic and stuff

            //Hiding progress bar and loading-text
            var mainPage = (MainPage)App.RootFrame.Content;
            mainPage.ProgressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            mainPage.ProgressText.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        });
}
```

So now my questions:

1. Is it possible to show the progress bar and loading-text at any pivot element that I navigated to?
2. As you see, by the reference "(MainPage)App.RootFrame.Content" I can reach my Progress-Bar/Text objects and simply set the attributes. But I don't like this way. 
   I thought there must be a way to set the Progress-Bar/Text with a {Binding ...} value which makes the code cleaner.
   Thus, how can I bind the attribute "Visibility" of ProgressBar and ProgressText so that they turn "visible" at start of LoadSomething() and that they turn "collapsed" when the handling finished?

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you almost solved it already, at least you described the solution for the second point.

1. This one is very easy, just put the TextBlock and ProgressBar under your Pivot in your xaml so they render ontop of the pivot element. You can then arrange them with HorizontalAlignment, VerticalAlignment and Margin. The code below should put them in the middle of your page:

   ```
   <phone:PhoneApplicationPage>

   ...

   <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
           <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
       </Grid.RowDefinitions>


       <phone:Pivot Title="MyTitle">
           <!-- Here are my PivotItems -->
       </phone:Pivot>

       <!-- HERE I want the progress bar and loading-text to show up if possible -->
           <TextBlock Name="ProgressText" Text="Loading..." Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
           <ProgressBar Name="ProgressBar" Visibility="Collapsed" IsIndeterminate="True" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
       <!-- HERE I want the progress bar and loading-text to show up if possible -->
   </Grid>

   <phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
   ```
2. Nearly as easy. I suspect your ViewModel implements INotifyPropertyChanged or derives from some class that does? If not, than do that. 
   Than add this Property to your ViewModel:

   ```
   private bool _IsLoading = false;

   public bool IsLoading
   {
       get { return _IsLoading; }
       set
       {
           if (_IsLoading != value)
           {
               _IsLoading = value;
               NotifyPropertyChanged("IsLoading");
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   (With NotifyPropertyChanged being your version of:

   ```
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
   public void NotifyPropertyChanged(String name)
   {
       PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
       if (handler != null)
           handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
   }
   ```

If you don't already have a BooleanToVisibilityConverter add this class to convert a boolean value to visibility in xaml:

```
public class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{


    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (value is bool && (bool)value) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value is Visibility && (Visibility)value == Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

On your MainPage creation you set the DataContext of either the whole page or just the TextBlock and ProgressBar to be your ViewModel (or you do it via Resources and xaml, but that doesn't matter), add the BooleanToVisibilityConverter as a Page resource like this:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
     <local:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
</phone:PhoneApplicationpage.Resources>
```

and bind the Visibility Properties of the TextBlock and ProgressBar to your IsLoading Property of your ViewModel:

```
<TextBlock Name="ProgressText" Text="Loading..." Visibility="{Binding IsLoading, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
<ProgressBar Name="ProgressBar" Visibility="{Binding IsLoading, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" IsIndeterminate="True" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

One last thing to do:

At the start of LoadSomething() you set `IsLoading = true;` and at the end of your HandleResponse method `IsLoading = false;` and that should do it.

Comment: Thank you, that totally made it work :)

I had the chapter with IValueConverter but I just forgot how to use it in combination with the property of an INotifyPropertyChanged object.